# cURL on ESXi 5.0?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

How can I get cURL work on a ESXi 5.0 server?

I know that cURL existed on previous versions of ESXi, for some reason there is no cURL in the latest ESXi.

I'm trying to find a way to run a statically compiled curl binary but I'm lost.

I know that a binary compiled statically on CentOS 3.9 would work on ESXi 4.1 and 4.0. But which version of CentOS I should use to do the same for ESXi 5.0?

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: As a general rule, SSH'ing into the ESXi host itself ought to be a very very rare thing. You should explain the bigger picture of what you're attempting to here, because it sounds like you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly advise you **NOT** to do this at all, the whole point of VMWare dropping ESX in favour of an ESXi-only product set was to discourage 'in-host' additions and tinkering. They want us to just build our hosts and leave them alone, something I personally understand, adhere to and encourage.

I don't know what you're actually trying to achieve but I'm sure you could get to that point using supported tools thus leaving your hosts to do what they do unfettled.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't try to run a binary like that on ESXi. It's not meant for that. Are you trying to download something directly to ESXi? If so, please try using `wget`. It's built-in.

```
Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [-s|--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document file]
        [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off] [-P DIR]
        [-U|--user-agent agent] url

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

Options:
        -s      Spider mode - only check file existence
        -c      Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
        -q      Quiet
        -P      Set directory prefix to DIR
        -O      Save to filename ('-' for stdout)
        -U      Adjust 'User-Agent' field
        -Y      Use proxy ('on' or 'off')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware of wget. However, I need curl's multi thread function.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. What are you trying to do?

Comment: So you want to run mulit-threaded code in ESXi's unsupported CLI? if so they you're NUTS!

Comment: ESXi's wget (part of busybox) doesn't support https.

Comment: @BastienDurel wget on ESXi finally started to support https. Yay! https://serverfault.com/questions/512888/vmware-esxi-help-downloading-large-iso/975328#975328

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to do this on a guest instead of the host and use the vcli to manipulate the host as required.  VSphere isn't really designed to run a full OS in the console VM.  Even if you got cURL running I suspect you'll hit other roadblocks.